# CS0161: not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, return

In the following C# snippet, I loop through all integers, up till x, and return as soon as a divisor of x is found.

```cs
class Program
{   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
        static int LowestDivisor(int x)
        {
            if (x < 0)
                x *= -1;
            if (x == 0 || x == 1)
                return -1;
            for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++)
            {
                if (x % i == 0)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see what causes the compiler to give the error `CS0161: not all code paths return a value`. In the case of a prime number, the last iteration of the for loop returns the prime. If not, a divisor would be returned in an earlier iteration. Hence, `for all code paths`, a value is returned. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can't know that on of the `if`s will eventually evaluate to `true`. You need some default return value after the `for` loop, even if it's never reached in practice:

```
static int LowestDivisor(int x)
{
    if (x < 0)
        x *= -1;
    if (x == 0 || x == 1)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++)
    {
        if (x % i == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    // Should never happen...
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not know that for any given input, if a value is not already caught in the first two `if`s, it will for sure return at some point in the `for` loop.

All it sees is that at some point there's a `for` with an `if` inside that for some values of `x` will exit without returning any value.

You could either add after the loop a `return 0` or a default value, or even `throw` an exception.